# How can I access android.developer site offline?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am a beginner,

I want to download all documentation of this site:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/index.html

But I cannot do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to download , it's already included in android sdk

so go to your android sdk folder and look for `docs` folder

e.g
`c:\....yourpath..\sdk\docs`  and in this folder look for something name as `index.html` page

Note: look for your sdk in the specific drive e.g E,D

most of site content will be there but don't expect the complete content/resources of other linked sites

Comment: Unfortunately, this is now out-of-date. It was true when posted, though.

Comment: the last time i checked with studio 3.0, the docs was there, hopefully , you have the complete sdk although i will confirm it and update the answer(if necessary) , thanks

Comment: the version currently available through android studio is from 2016. The front page refers to Android 2.1 as the latest.

Answer (score 3):

I am posting an answer because as of the latest **Android Studio(2.3)**, it is found in your **`AppData`** directory which is *hidden* by default. Find it here:

```
C:\Users\<Your User Name>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\docs\
```

You can start with `index.html` and post opening, you will find the search in the top right hand side corner.

Answer (score 2):

A few days ago I downloaded all of the documents available on the site
 https://developer.android.com/
 for my own personal use. These documents are now uploaded to Google Drive as two separate archives for public usage,
 in the hope that it will be useful to those who need it, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY.

The first archive is:
[android-developers-docs-2020-02-23.tar.xz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10VM_UC5vuBw0HIzhbHtHfPWD963t4QH4/view?usp=sharing)
 with the following specifications:

- the size of the archive file is: 925 M
- disk usage after extraction is: 17.9 G
- number of files in the archive is: 36735
- code samples are not included in this archive.

The second archive (for those who need to access code samples offline too) is:
[android-developers-gits-2020-02-23.tar.xz](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mBzxcyDCWaOqR_NSMpp8oPyxr3i1-k3n/view?usp=sharing)
with the following specifications:

- the size of the archive file is: 6.6 G
- disk usage after extraction is: 9.1 G
- number of files in the archive is: 200030
- this archive should be extracted in the same directory as the first one.

After unpacking the second archive file, please do:

```
cd android-developers-docs
mv github.com  github.com.OLD
ln -fs github.com.git github.com
```